# Keycodes for arrow keys

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

Can anyone please help me to get the keycodes for the arrow keys in c# .net keypress events? Can you help me to get out of this check point?

best regards,
Arun.

Answer (score 14):

Do you mean the KeyUp event? KeyPress doesn't get fired for Arrows and the event args doesn't have a KeyCode property but for Arrow Keys in keyUp event they are:

Keys.Up, Keys.Down, Keys.Left, Keys.right

Answer (score 5):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx

Keys.Up, Keys.Left, Keys.Right, Keys.Down.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the keycodes here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa243025(v=vs.60).aspx

It states:

```
vbKeyLeft   37  LEFT ARROW key
vbKeyUp     38  UP ARROW key
vbKeyRight  39  RIGHT ARROW key
vbKeyDown   40  DOWN ARROW key
```

You can use it to compare like this

```
e.KeyValue==39
```